# Remove audio Tracks from a video file

Tags: 14.04, sound, video, video-conversion

I have a bunch of video files with 2 audio tracks. They are avi files. The audio tracks have no labels and when I try to play them the default track has no audio. There are 2 more tracks, the second is the one with audio.

Is there a command I could run that would remove tracks 1 and 3 from every file?

They are on a Ubuntu server. CLI only.

```
avprobe version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[mpeg4 @ 0xd1dac0] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Input #0, avi, from 'Video004.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)
  Duration: 00:49:16.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1937 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 32000 Hz, 1 channels, s16p, 96 kb/s
    Stream #0.2: Audio: mp3, 32000 Hz, 1 channels, s16p, 96 kb/s
    Stream #0.3: Audio: mp3, 32000 Hz, 1 channels, s16p, 96 kb/s
# avprobe output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avconv seems to be the solution

```
avconv -i $file -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -acodec copy -vcodec copy $outfile
```

I put this into a loop

```
dir="*.avi"
for file in $dir
do 
 avconv -i $file -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -acodec copy -vcodec copy $outfile
done
```

I did not try saving to the same file name but I assume it would not work. You can easily have this delete the old file and rename the new one. I just output to a temp directory with the same names and then moved them all overwriting the originals.

To explain The map arg. tells avconv what tracks to copy. 0:0 is the video and 0:2 is the second audio track. Then acodec and vcodec are set to copy meaning it copies the audio and video without changing it.

Comment: after trying your method i get this message, `Stream map '0:2' matches no streams. To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.` So I add `?` and it worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/03/how-to-use-sox-audio-editing.htmlhttp://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/03/how-to-use-sox-audio-editing.html?m=1).  Scroll down until you reach **Convert Mono Audio to Stereo and Vice Versa** and try that.  It allows you to turn a stereo track into a Mono track by choosing one of the channels.

Comment: Unfortunatly thats just for audio files.

Comment: Would it work with this? http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=using:command_line_usage

Comment: Either choose the track, or extract the track, edit it with the first tool, and then choose that one

Comment: so `--save-raw-audio` maybe. Will it actually remove the audio from the avi or just copy? I dont see any argument to select which audio track to extract.

Comment: Check out the Re-encoding a soundtrack to MP3 VBR

Section.  Save the raw audio, process it using the first program, and then save it to the avi again

Comment: Actually This led me to avconv. Thanks for the help though. AVdemux would likely work too but I think avconv is a bit easier. I also noticed a lot of issues with framerate issues when you dont set one. And these files are all a bit different.